# Imprisoned with a note

Tags: cipher, story

Once upon a time, a man was imprisoned by a corrupt leader in a cellar. Every day, a servant would come by and give him a singular piece of bread. One day, he was given a note. On the note, there was written a line of letters:

```
 ANNNWDSLBUT•AOTO••OA•I•THTPO•OIT•YCMO•ERDR
```

What happened, and what should he do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what you should do:

> *At noon in two days, climb out the trapdoor.*

The note ...

> ... is encrypted with a transposition cipher. The message is 42 characters long. Rearrange them in three lines of 14 characters:
>
> ```
>     A N N N W D S L B U T • A O
>     T O • • O A • I • T H T P O
>     • O I T • Y C M O • E R D R
> ```
>
> Now read the message column-wise. The dots are spaces.

Comment: Fitting that you waited this long. ;)

Comment: Yes, but here it's closer to midnight than to noon. (That gives me more than 12h to find the trapdoor.)

Comment: Good job. I didn't even know that btransposition cipher was something. I thought I had made it up. Thanks for showing me that I didn't make it up.